# Vim syntax: Highlight a match only at the beginning of a region

Tags: vim

I am writing vim syntax highlighting for a DSL where functions follow the following format:

```
# A function with no arguments
<function>

# A function with arguments
<function(arg1, arg2)>

# A function with text
<function block of normal text>

# A function with args and text
<function(arg1,arg2) text>

# Line breaks are allowed pretty much everywhere.
<function(
        arg1,
        arg2)
    a block of text>

# As is nesting
<function(<subfunc>) Some text with <another(subfunction) etc.>>

# Backslash escape
<function(single arg with a comma: "\,") contained bracket between quotes: "\>">
```

It's a text-processing language (think markdown on steroids), so the text blocks must be non-restrictive.

I'm having a lot of trouble writing a vim syntax file for this.

I can do

```
syn region myFunction start='<' end='>' skip='\\>'
syn region myArgs start='(' end=')' skip='\\)'
```

But `myFunction` can't contain `myArgs`, because then the parens are wrongly highlighted in the following example:

```
<function(arg) some text (with parenthesis) that aren't arguments>
```

Specifically, I want the function name and argument list to be highlighted only at the immediate beginning of the region. However, I can't do

```
syn region myFunction start='<(regex to match name and arg list)' ...
```

Because, even if `regex to match name and arg list` weren't horrifying, this breaks my ability to syntax highlight nested functions.

What I want is something like `nextgroup` for the `start` of a `syntax region`, but I can't find one.

Is this possible? How do I do this in vimscript?

Comment: Are you sure about the `start='\<'`? `\<` matches the beginning of a word; to match a literal `<`, use `<`.

Comment: Oh, right -- I use '\v' in front of all my regexes and stripped them for clarity, forgetting that < doesn't need escaping afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a contained syntax match for the function name that overlaps with the leading `<` character of the `myFunction` region, then use `nextgroup` to attempt a match with `myArgs` only directly after it, not subsequent occurrences.

```
:syn region myFunction start='<' end='>' contains=myFunctionName
:syn match myFunctionName '<\i\+' contained nextgroup=myArgs
:syn region myArgs start='(' end=')' contained
```

Edit: Here's a variant with `matchgroup` on the `<...>` elements; the `matchgroup` cannot be used for the start element, because that prevents the anchoring of `myFunctionName`:

```
:syn region myFunction start='<' matchgroup=myMarker end='>' contains=myFunctionName
:syn match myFunctionName '<\i\+' contained nextgroup=myArgs contains=myMarker
:syn match myMarker '<' contained
:syn region myArgs start='(' end=')' contained
```

Comment: This fails if [matchgroup] is used on the myFunction region. Is that intentional or a vim bug?

Comment: Then the `<` is "consumed" by the matchgroup, and no additional matching is attempted; I've added an alternative to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can also try these for finer control on the highlights:

```
syn region myFunction start='<' end='[^\\]>' contains=myFunctionName
syn match myFunctionName '<\i\+'hs=s+1 contained nextgroup=myArgs
syn region myArgs start='('hs=s+1 end=')'he=s-1 contained contains=myFunction
```

Comment: What are `hs`, `s`, and `he` doing here? Where do they come from?

Comment: They are used for specifying the part that should be highlighted. You can check out ":syn-pattern-offset" in VIM.